# Change default speed of animate.css classes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animate.css

I want to add animate.css classes on scrollbar changes, i mean when the scroll get down the div should animate with animated fadeInUp but the speed of the animation should slow. i have tested with jQuery animate() function but its not working for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
var scrolls = $(window).scrollTop();
   if(scrolls > 900){//from top to 900px my div appears
       $(".box-animate").animate({function(){
                 $(this).addClass("animated fadeInUp");
                 }
                  },3000);
           }
           });
   });
```

I know there is some stupidity exists in my code:) but i am not able to find it?

Comment: You're right, something is wrong with the code, jQuery's `animate()` animates CSS values *(and other things)*, but you can't just stick an `addClass` inside it, and hope it works, it won't.

Comment: $(this).addClass("animated fadeInUp") create problem, but how to do it instead this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animate.css is just CSS. You don't need to alter it with jQuery, you can create your own custom classes based on the classes it supplies with your own speed settings.

If you definitely want three seconds for every animation, you can just change the default `animated` class in the file:

```
.animated {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Place the class `animated` on the element you want to animate, and then you can trigger an animation with:

```
$('.box-animate').addClass("fadeInUp");
```

You don't need to be using jQuery's `.animate` at all.

Comment: Yes it was perfect answer.